# Ignore case while using duplicated

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I am using the duplicated function in R to remove the duplicate rows in my data frame.

```
 df:

 Name Rank
  A    1
  a    1
  B    2


df[!duplicated(df),]

 Name Rank
  A    1
  a    1
  B    2
```

The second row is same as the first, but doesn't get deleted just because it takes the case of the **"A" and "a"** in to consideration. What is the turn around this? Thanks.

Comment: See `?tolower`.

Comment: I was about to say the same thing as @Roland. If you can't change the case tho let us know because there's a work around for that.

Comment: @Hack-R Thanks.That would be changing everything to the lower case but I cannot do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# If it's okay to change the case
df.lower      <- df
df.lower$Name <- tolower(df$Name)

df.lower[!duplicated(df.lower$Name),]

# If you don't want to change the case
df[!duplicated(df.lower$Name),]
```

or simply

```
df[!duplicated(tolower(df$Name)),]
```

> ```
>   Name Rank
> 1    A    1
> 3    B    2
> ```

That's for deduping based on `Name`. For the entire row you could do:

```
df.lower[!duplicated(df.lower),] # changes the case
```

or

```
df[!duplicated(cbind(tolower(df$Name),df$Rank)),] # does not change case
```